# language of forcing

Tags: set-theory

Occasionally (e.g., in Sheppard, *The Logic of Infinity*, 11.3.3), set forcing is presented in such a way that the forcing language is simply added up front as a supplement to the predicate calculus with a membership relation symbol.  One then carries out the whole argument in the enriched language (containing constants for all elements of the generic extension) and shows that a condition forces the Goedel number of a formula just when the generic extension satisfies the formula.  One concludes (I think) that if there is a countable transitive model (*ctm*) of *ZF(C)* with the enriched vocabulary, that there is such a model of *ZF(C) + ~CH* in that vocabulary.  My question is: how does one turn this into an argument that, assuming a ctm of *ZF(C)* in the original vocabulary of set theory, there is such a model of *ZF(C) + ~CH* in that vocabulary?  (If the answer is simple, this would seem to allow for a more accessible presentation of forcing.  One wouldn't need to start with the complicated definition of names in the initial model.)

Comment: You can always expand your vocabulary to include symbols for definable relations. The forcing theorem says that the forcing relation is definable for every fixed formula in the forcing language.

Comment: Thanks -- I take your point to be that it doesn't matter whether you introduce names by hand or build them out of sets in the original model so long as you can prove the forcing theorem, which seems right.  But what is the theorem that lets you say that if Con(ZF*), then Con(ZF), where ZF* is ZF but in the language enriched with constants?

Comment: This follows from the completeness and soundness theorems: Con(ZF) implies a model of ZF implies a model of ZF* implies Con(ZF*).